# Is there a `stdlib` or `pandas` equivalent to the following simple `is_in` function?

Tags: python, list

Is there a `stdlib` or `pandas` equivalent to the following simple `is_in` function? (Seems so simple, but I haven't found it yet)

```
def is_in(x, y):
'''
:param x: a list of values of length n
:param y: a list of values of any length
:return: a list of Boolean values, corresponding to if
 each value in x is in y.

Example:
x = [1,15,[1,2,3],'a', 'Sandy', {'a':[4]}]
y = [[1,2,3], 15, 'Sand', {'a':[4]}]
is_in(x,y)
# returns:
# [False, True, True, False, False, True]
'''
idx = [xx in y for xx in x]
return idx
```

Same thing for:

```
def subset(x, idx):
'''
:param x: a list of values of length n
:param idx: a list of Boolean (True, False) values of length n
:return: a list of all x values for which the corresponding Boolean
 value (x[i] <--> idx[i]) was True

Example:
import numpy as np
idx = [True, False, np.nan, True]
x = [1,2,3,4]
subset(x, idx)
# returns: [1,4]

'''
xx = [x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if idx[i]==True]
return xx
```

Comment: `[ i in y for i in x ]`?

Comment: Yeah - thanks - that seems better / faster. --> updated

Comment: Is that last element really supposed to be `true`? `{'a':[4]} != {'a':[3]}`

Comment: Also, `[ i[0] for i in zip(x, idx) if i[1] ]` for the second one is perhaps more *pythonic*.

Comment: @Phylogenesis oops yes :) supposed to be False - thanks

Comment: And looking at this some more, it seems as though you what you *really* want to do is combine these together: `[ i for i in x if i in y ]` (Returns a list of everything in x that is in y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably fastest:

```
map(y.__contains__, x)
```

For second part of the question there is `itertools.compress`